# How can I copy a file on the server using JSch's SCP support?

Tags: java, ssh, scp, jsch

I managed to create a method which uploads a file into a directory.

How would I have to change this so I could copy a file from /123.html to /en/123.html via JSch?

```
public void upFile(String source, String fileName, String destination) throws Exception {
    try {

        try {
            // 改变当前路径
            client.cd(destination);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("当前目录不存在，新建目录！");
            JschCreateDir.createDir(host, port, username, password, destination);
            client.cd(destination);
        }

        // 上传本地文件 到当前目录
        File file = new File(source + fileName);
        client.put(new FileInputStream(file), fileName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logout();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: If you are already on the server (with your `client` object) and note that a directory doesn't exist, then use this connection to create the new directory, not a separate one in your `createDir` method.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question that you want to copy a file on the server from one directory to another one (and not a local file to the server, which your code already seems to do).

Unfortunately, the SFTP protocol (which is implemented by JSch's ChannelSFTP class) doesn't support copying directly on the server.
You certainly can combine the `put` and `get` to copy the file from one location to another, but this will send the contents twice through the wire from server to client and back.

A better way would be to use an `exec` channel, and simply directly issue the server's system's copy command. On a unixoid server, this would be `cp  /123.html /en/123.html`.  (This assumes you have shell access to the server, not an sftp-only access, as I already did see somewhere.)

Here is some code (not tested, you might need to add exception handling):

```
public void copyFile(Session session, String sourceFile, String destinationFile) {
    ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    channel.setCommand("cp " + sourceFile + " " + destinationFile);
    channel.connect();
    while(channel.isConnected()) {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }
    int status = channel.getExitStatus();
    if(status != 0)
      throw new CopyException("copy failed, exit status is " + status);
}
```

Comment: great @Paŭlo Ebermann. One minor correction: session.openChannel("exec");